# How to negate regex using test

Tags: bash, shell, regular-expression

This is syntactically wrong:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dimension="4x5"

if [[ "$dimension" !=~ '[0-9]x[0-9]' ]]; then
 echo 'wtf meng, the dimension needs an "x" in it.'
 return 1;
fi
```

the above has bad syntax...so my question is - is there a way to do `!=~`

...I am guessing it's `!~` ? If that's true, so much for negation rules lulz. Alright I tested it and `!~` doesn't work either..

Comment: If by "test" in the title you mean `test` then note `[[` is not `test`, `[` is. And `test` (or `[`) does not support regex.

Comment: ahh I thought [[ was test, but I guess not..then what is [[ called? thx

Comment: `[[` could be called an _extended test command_ https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS

Comment: what do you mean with "so much for negation rules"?

Comment: logic stuff means if you slap on a ! to the front of anything it should negate it. So I should be able to do `!!!!true` and the computer should understand it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no `!=~` or `!~` operators for the `[[` keyword. Instead, negate the result of the comparison:

```
[[ ! "string" =~ regex ]]
```

Regarding quoting the `regex` argument, the manual states:

> Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force the quoted portion to be matched as  a  string.

So regular expression parts of the `regex` should not be quoted – unless the shell option `compat31` is set:

> `shopt` ... `compat31`
>
> If set, bash changes its behavior to that of version 3.1 with respect to quoted arguments to the `[[` conditional command's `=~` operator

For the given example, try:

```
if [[ ! "$dimension" =~ ^[0123456789]+x[0123456789]+$ ]]; then
    printf '%s %s\n' "'$dimension'" 'is not a valid dimension.'
fi
```

- `regex` should be anchored with `^...$`, otherwise `foo1x1fubar` would be considered a valid dimension.

Also remember not to use ranges like `0-9` for input validation, especially if it's for sanitisation in security-sensitive contexts, as in many locales, these ranges include a lot more characters (or possibly collating elements made of several characters) than they did historically (and still do in the C/POSIX locale).

For `=~`, `bash`'s `globasciiranges` doesn't help here. On Ubuntu 19.10 and in the `en_GB.UTF-8` locale, I find  that `bash`'s `[0-9]` matches on 1040 different characters in addition to 0123456789, with or without `globasciiranges`. At least in my case they all bare some relation with decimal digits 0 to 8, but that's not even guaranteed in general.

On the other hand, `[[:digit:]]` and `[0123456789]` matches only on those 10 and should on any POSIX compliant system.

You could also do it using standard `sh` syntax and wildcard patterns with something like:

```
valid_geometry() case $1 in
  (*[!x0123456789]* | *x | x* | *x*x*) false;;
  (*x*) true;;
  (*) false;;
esac
if ! valid_geometry "$dimension"; then
   ...
fi
```

Or with ksh globs (as also supported by `bash -O extglob` and `bash`'s `[[` even without `extglob`) with:

```
if [[ $dimension != +([0123456789])x+([0123456789]) ]]; then
  ...
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Alright so this seems to work:

```
if [[ ! "$dimension" =~ [0-9]+x[0-9]+ ]]; then
 echo 'wtf meng, the dimension needs an "x" in it.'
 exit 1;
fi
```

but I am wondering why wrapping it in single-quotes does not work:

```
if [[ ! "$dimension" =~ '[0-9]+x[0-9]+' ]]; then
 echo 'wtf meng, the dimension needs an "x" in it.'
 exit 1;
fi
```

here is my solution:

```
dimension="3x5"

regex='[0-9]+x[0-9]+'

if [[ ! "$dimension" =~ $regex ]]; then
 echo 'wtf meng, the dimension needs an "x" in it.'
 exit 1;
fi
```

Now you can use single quotation marks to quote the regex, but you must avoid the double quotes when referencing $regex from within [[ ]]. However I am still curious if there is shorthand for `[0-9]+`..

Comment: You might want to anchor that regex: `^[0-9]+x[0-9]+$`

Comment: For one, wouldn't that merit a question in its own right? The answer is that - as stated in the accepted answer - "Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force the quoted portion to be matched as a string".So, if you single-quote the RegExp, it will no longer be intepreted as RegExp! Your "workaround" worked because `$regex` only contains `[0-9]+x[0-9]+`, _without_ the quotes. They are only interpreted at the moment of the assignment, to make sure `$regex` takes on the value in between them without any interpretation/interpretation by the shell. Try `echo "$regex"` to verify...